# What does it mean in Maven when it says the following artifacts could not be resolved although they are in Maven cache?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I get the following error:

The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Failure to find com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1 in https://artifactory.corp.adobe.com/artifactory/maven-identity-snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of artifactory-snapshot

However, both jars are in the Maven cache (.m2 folder) on my machine. I mean files named: jmxri-1.2.1.jar and jmxtools-1.2.1.jar. They are respectively in the folders com/sun/jmdk/jmxtools/1.2.1/ and com/sun/jmx/jmxri/1.2.1

EDIT: When I try the -o switch on Maven to force it to use the local jars, it says the artifact has not been downloaded before. Which is probably true since indeed the artifact is not in the repo but was copied from some other place to my Maven cache -- is it possible to force Maven to use the jars? The -o switch does not seem to force this and Maven seems to be able to detect that the artifact was not downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete corresponding artifact folders in maven local repo and rerun or just rerun using -U flag.

> Which is probably true since indeed the artifact is not in the repo but was copied from some other place to my Maven cache

Manually copying jars is not the correct way to put artifacts into maven local repo. You should use mvn install:install-file instead. More details here: [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Answer (score 0):

The dependency on those jars is usually a consequence of a bug in the pom.xml for log4j 1.2.15.

Update to 1.2.16 or 1.2.17 and you will not need these jars any longer.

These particular artefacts date back to a time when Sun licensing did not permit the hosting of the actual jars in a public maven repository.

You were required to accept licence conditions, download them yourself and then manually install either into your local repo (using `mvn install:install-file`) or into your corporate repository manager (typically using a UI that it provides or `mvn deploy:deploy-file`).